# how to put parameter default value into generated code in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

swagger parameter default is not in generated code.
for example:

```
   paths:
  /user/refresh.json:
    post:
      operationId: refresh
      description: |
        By passing in the appropriate options, you can search for
        available inventory in the system
      produces:
      - application/json
      consumes: 
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      parameters:
      - name: "RC-App-Key"
        in: "header"
        description: appkey..
        required: true
        default: "abc"
        type: "string"
```

the generated code like

public class DevelopersApiTest {

```
private final DevelopersApi api = new DevelopersApi();

@Test
public void refreshTest() throws ApiException {
    String rcAppKey = null;
    Common response = api.refresh(rcAppKey);

    // TODO: test validations
}
```

the rcAppKey is null,but i want it be the default value "abc",like:

```
String rcAppKey = "abc";
Common response = api.refresh(rcAppKey);
```

the default value is not in generated code,but in .md file,how to put the default value into the code?

Comment: did you find any solution? i am also looking for that.

Comment: In this example, the parameter is marked as `required: true`. Required parameters [cannot have default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49570369/113116).