# Using `default` with `required` parameters for OpenAPI

Tags: openapi

The [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#common-mistakes-10) says:

> Using `default` with `required` parameters or properties, for example, with path parameters. This does not make sense – if a value is required, the client must always send it, and the default value is never used.

But this is common idiom for databases when column `IS NOT NULL` and have `DEFAULT`, is not?

Why for OpenAPI this makes no sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of function declarations. Consider JavaScript string method [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
"string".indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

The `searchValue` parameter is required and must always be supplied. It does not have a default value - the client must always provide the substring they want to find.

The `fromIndex` parameter is optional, and the default value is 0.

Now, if the required parameter `searchValue` had a default value, it would mean this parameter is no longer required! It's now optional, as in:

```
"string".indexOf([searchValue[, fromIndex]])
```

That's why the `defalut` value is an attribute of optional parameters and not `required` parameters.

Parameters in OpenAPI follow the same principle. The `default` value is for documentation purposes only, to tell the client developers what value the server will use if a client does not supply an optional parameter.

Comment: So from the script side if we want a parameter always passed. We just sets up `default`