# Display default value of a model attribute in Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Spring Boot Java and Swagger 2 to document my APIs.
What Spring annotation can I use to show the default value `mydoggie` in Swagger UI?

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control of swagger file default property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818575/control-of-swagger-file-default-property)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an example and a default value to show in Swagger 2 with this annotation:

`@ApiModelProperty(value = "value to show", example = "example to show")`

I hope it helps

Comment: @ApiModelProperty(value= "description ") is only for displaying a description of the property. http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#value()

Comment: @SaraSara Unfortunately there is no other option if you stay with Swagger 2.0. However OpenAPI 3.0 does provide the example attribute. In my project with Swagger 2.0 I resolve this issue by adding information about the default value to the description field like this  `@ApiModelProperty(value = "my value (default: my default value)")`