# Is it possible to have a required query parameter with a default value on FastAPI?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, openapi

I am trying to make a query parameter required but give it a default value on FastAPI, but i am not finding anything on their user guide.

On openapi, it would be something like this:

```
parameters:
      - name: "some_name"
        in: "query"
        description: "a description"
        required: true
        type: "string"
        default: "First"
        enum:
        - "First"
        - "Second"
        - "Third"
```

as you can see required is assigned to true and i have a default value ("first")
With fastapi i have this:

```
class ModelNames(str, Enum):
  first = "first"
  second = "second"
  third = "third"


@app.post("/path")
async def this_function(
    modelInstance = Query(
      default=Required, # i would like to somehow assign "first" and Required to default 
      description="a description"
    )
  ):
  return None
```

I've tried directly assigning "first" but it makes it optional.

Comment: Could you clarify, why do you need a default on required parameter? What behavior do you expect? Could example data be more appropriate for your usage case? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/

Comment: @pavel-vergeev i have a web app that was created years ago with close to no documentation and it's not running, the app uses an api that was created using some old libraries and we couldn't find the versions that were used, so i am trying to create an api that behaves exactly the same because it will be time consuming to dig in the application's code and change the calls. So i am trying to have the default values that were on the old api but still have them required.

Comment: In OpenAPI, required parameters [cannot have a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49570369/113116). Default value is for optional parameters only. If you want to have a pre-selected value in Swagger UI, add an `example` value instead, as @PavelVergeev suggested.

Comment: @mazs What do you want to happen if someone doesnt pass in any value for that query parameter?

Comment: @TomMcLean if no value is assigned, the default value is sent

Comment: @mazs Whats wrong with having a default value?

Comment: If you can choose to not pass a query parameter (and thereby get the default value), that's kind of the definition of an optional parameter?

Comment: @M.O. but you can't assign "None" to it, so it's not really optional.

Comment: @TomMcLean that's the thing, i want a default value.

Comment: @mazs So what you really want is a field where you can either pass no value, or a value but it cant be None? Because you can do that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Required parameter can't get default value by design

You can't.

If you want to define a default value for the side effect of a custom example value, use the example parameter instead.

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#example-and-examples-in-openapi

Comment: I see, i thought that there may be a way.
Thank you